# how can I play multiple videos simultaneously using opencv in python?

Tags: python, opencv

Hi guys I am stuck at this point. I want to play four videos on my screen using opencv . Can anyone help me how to do that? Suppose I want to play simultaneously

1. first.avi
2. second.avi
3. third.avi
4. fourth.avi

I am referring following code. It plays very well for single avi file.
Is it necessary to concatenate or  i can run in four different windows?. any suggestions are welcome
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

```
# Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file
# If the input is the camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('first.avi')
cap2 =cv2.VideoCapture('second.avi')

if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
  print("Error opening video stream or file")
if (cap2.isOpened()== False): 
  print("Error opening video stream or file")

while(cap.isOpened()||cap2.isOpened()):
  # Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  ret, frame1 = cap2.read()
  if ret == True:

   # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame1)


   # Press Q on keyboard to  exit
   if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
  break
  else: 
    break


cap.release()
cap2.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Just read all and display?

Comment: I know that while capturing from camera      cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) cap1 =cv2.VideoCapure(1) works well  but while playing video from file its not working properly

Comment: i tried to read all but it is overlapping in same frame

Comment: use different names in imshow for each camera

Comment: i am not using camera.@api55   @Silencer it is for a single  image there is no reference for videos anywhere including your link.

Comment: if it was that easy there would have been many posts. not even a single post for running multiple videos simultaneously @Silencer

Comment: I do not get the "overlapping in same frame" from your comment before? could you post an image of it and the corresponding code?

Comment: @api55... I think what the OP meant by "overlapping" is that frames from multiple videos are being displayed in a single window in the order in which they are being captured.

Comment: @sgarizvi that was my guess, and that is why i suggested diffrent names in imshow function... just that i said camera instead of video....

Comment: Thanks @sgarizvi you saved my time dude ..otherwise nowdays people are more interested in voting down negative .. than helping others

Comment: @api55 I got you . what you wanted to say.. just by changing the name of frame . imshow will produce the another frame... .Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For playing multiple videos, we have to use unique window titles for each video. Here is a sample code demonstrating how it can be achieved.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

names = ['first.avi', 'second.avi', 'third.avi', 'fourth.avi'];
window_titles = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']


cap = [cv2.VideoCapture(i) for i in names]

frames = [None] * len(names);
gray = [None] * len(names);
ret = [None] * len(names);

while True:

    for i,c in enumerate(cap):
        if c is not None:
            ret[i], frames[i] = c.read();


    for i,f in enumerate(frames):
        if ret[i] is True:
            gray[i] = cv2.cvtColor(f, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            cv2.imshow(window_titles[i], gray[i]);

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break


for c in cap:
    if c is not None:
        c.release();

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**P.S:** This code is just a quick and dirty example for demo purpose only. Tested with python 2 and OpenCV 3.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: is it possible to play them in the same window without a pause ?

Comment: @Fadolphin. Yes it is possible, by providing the same window name for each image in the `cv2.imshow` call. Also, my opinion is to create the window beforehand and resizing it to fixed size by calling `cv2.namedWindow` and `cv2.resizeWindow` respectively before the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you sir. You saved my program a great amount of resources. I was using moviepy to merge them both into one video, then play it in a single window. it takes about 60 seconds just for the the merge to commence.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Optimised code and worked for me

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 


cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture('1.mp4')
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture('2.mp4')
while cap1.isOpened() or cap2.isOpened():

    okay1  , frame1 = cap1.read()
    okay2 , frame2 = cap2.read()

    if okay1:
        hsv1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1 , cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        cv2.imshow('fake' , hsv1)

    if okay2:
        hsv2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2 , cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        cv2.imshow('real' , hsv2)

    if not okay1 or not okay2:
        print('Cant read the video , Exit!')
        break

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    
    cv2.waitKey(1)

cap1.release()
cap2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```